# Why does Minecraft say that 'mob:ghast:fireball' does not exist?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a nether portal normally, but the game crashed when I started it.  It said:

> File minecraft:sounds/mob/ghast/fireball.ogg does not exist

What does that mean?  Please help me fix it.

Comment: Does it say File minecraft:sounds/mob/ghast/fireball.ogg does not exist?

Comment: yes it does. Do I need to do something about it?

Comment: Well, you need to be as precise as possible in questions. So go use that edit button and edit in the specific error message. :)

Answer (score 7):

Probably a bug, if it can get to the update/login menu, just re download your version of minecraft. otherwise go to explorer and in the bar type '%appdata%', go to the minecraft file and delete everything. Then run your minecraft.exe and it'll redownload your version of minecraft.

Comment: Maybe you should add the information that he should save his worlds so he is able to play them after he deleted everything...

Comment: He should only delete the versions folder...